# Is there a way to interpret CSV cell splitting symbol in C#?

Tags: c#, csv

As I started saving CSV files, I noticed that not always the rows are separated by comma(,), but by semi-colon (;). Is there a way to inscribe this in C# that it should separate the cells into different strings no matter if it is semi-colon or comma.

I have a template that contains 2 columns: Name, Property

The name is pretty straight forward, but the property may contain several values separated by comma.

Example:

```
Name1; Property1, Property2, Property3
Name2; Property2, Property3
Name3; Property1
```

Now what I need to understand is: Does C# has a function that recognizes the cell-splitting symbol, because it might be (,) or (;)?
And if the same data is represented with a comma:

```
Name1, Property1, Property2, Property3
Name2, Property2, Property3
Name3, Property1
```

How should I go by separating without ending up with more columns than I require or is that even possible?

Comment: You could use `str.Split(',',';')`. However, are you sure that the fields don't contain one of both delimiters?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you don't want to parse CSV manually but you want to use a library that does it for you (like FileHelpers), if we generalize your question to "How to split a string by multiple characters" the answer is basic, the Split method takes an array of char as splitting characters so you can use whatever you want.

Comment: `string.Split(';', ',');` but..[Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser!](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble)

Comment: Just to elaborate on what Reniuz said, parsing CSV files yourself is a bad idea! In fact, CSV's are often misused which makes them a poor format to use in my opinion. If the output is intended for human consumption, then an Open Office XML Spreadsheet (.xlsx) file is more appropriate. If it's intended for passing data between programs, then XML or JSON are good choices.

Comment: Do you want to write CSV so that Excel can read it? If so Excel uses a separator based on the culture (; in de-de e.g.). You can get the same separator through System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator Note that you have to escape that separator in the text of a field (or just always properly escape the field).

If you want to read it you can't really be sure which separator excel used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**String.Split**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is your friend, it accepts params array of chars which should be considered for splitting.

```
string[] cells = line.Split(',',';')
```

You can even exclude empty values if you like with the **StringSplitOptions** overload.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to parse delimited files.  It has a delimiters property that you can set to whatever the delimiter is for the file:

```
TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser("C:\\File.txt");
tfp.Delimiters = new[] {",", ";"};

var fields = tfp.ReadFields();
```

The advantage of this over `String.Split` is it will handle quoted fields by just setting a flag.  Also it will handle input that contains CRLF if it is enclosed in quotes.